# In HLSL, how to set all values of array?

Tags: arrays, variable-assignment, assign, hlsl

Is there a way to set all values of an array after initialization with a single line of code?

For example, I can do this: `int array[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }`.

However, later on I cannot simply write: `array = {4, 3, 2, 1};` to set the array to something else.

Would definitely guess cause it does not know that `{4, 3, 2, 1}` is an array of ints, but then how do I tell it that it is?

I have found workarounds like:

```
int tempArray[4] = {4, 3, 2, 1};
array = tempArray[4];
```

or

```
array[0] = 4;
array[1] = 3;
array[2] = 2;
array[3] = 1;
```

However I would definitely prefer not to have to use those workarounds, but instead have something like `array = int[4] {4, 3, 2, 1};`.

Comment: Just had this same question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74647642/4692342), it doesn't seem possible currently. The alternative is to use a `static const` array (which is very similar to your `tempArray` workaround), e.g.:

```
static const int constArray[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

array = constArray;
```